# VSCode not connected to the internet

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to run an pre-trained ml model on vscode and i require internet access because i am using torch.hub.load(), but this is the error that i am getting. Im not sure how to connect to the internet from vscode.

This is the code and the error:

Code:

```
import torch

import torchvision

import numpy as np

def main():


    # load the model
    model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path='model_params.pt')

    # run model on fake data by calling it like a function call
    img = np.random.randn(1024,764,3)
    boxes = model(img, size=640)
    print(boxes)
```

error:

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/hub.py", line 199, in _get_cache_or_reload
repo_owner, repo_name, ref = _parse_repo_info(github)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/hub.py", line 156, in _parse_repo_info
raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: It looks like there is no internet connection and the repo could not be found in the cache (/Users/.../.cache/torch/hub)

Comment: It's only a Visual Studio Code problem is that same code works elsewhere. Have you tried that?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I tried it on just pure IDLE but im getting the same error. Not sure what else i should run it on

Comment: Please incorporate this information into the question and tag accordingly. You can't fix a Python library from your text editor.

Answer (score 0):

If you work on MacOS:
`Macintosh HD -> Programms -> Python (your version) -> Install certificates.commands`

How it's works:

In /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/hub.py you have script, where python insert full link on git, that same your fragment: `'ultralytics/yolov5'`. It unpacks into two variables repo_... and start parse yolo GitHub. But when launched, it checks the SSL, which your pc does not provide. As the result Install certificates.commands setup certificate and it`s works